# Pandas truncate DataFrame rows that come before row that contains certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with column that contains strings like `90j1`, that are unique. Dataframe is already sorted by that column. What I need is truncate all rows that come before row that contains certain value. Here is example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['90j1', '90j2', '90j3'])
print(df)
#       0
# 0  90j1
# 1  90j2
# 2  90j3
```

For example, I need to truncate rows that come before row with `90j2`. Expected output will be:

```
print(truncated_df)
#       0
# 0  90j2
# 1  90j3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.truncate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
df.truncate(after=df.loc[df[0] == '90j2'].index[0])
```

or simple indexing:

```
df.loc[:df.loc[df[0] == '90j2'].index[0]]
```

Both result in:

```
      0
0  90j1
1  90j2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using `.iloc`

```
df.iloc[df.loc[df[0]=='90j2'].index[0]:,:]
Out[356]: 
      0
1  90j2
2  90j3
```